# Getting ip addresses from json file using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a script to get a list of ip address in a section of a json file. If the name is equal to AzureCloud.westeurope. The name and the ips are at different levels of the json file:

[image]

In my script I get my Json file and ConvertFrom-Json. I search the list of names to match AzureCloud.westeurope and then want to return the list of ips that are associated with that name.
I then try to return the ips if the object name is equal to AzureCloud.westeurope.
But the $ips variables is empty after I run my script.
What am I dong wrong?

```
function GetIpListForRegion {
$data = (Get-Content $output | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach($property in $data.values.name) {
    if($property -eq "AzureCloud.westeurope") {    
        $ips = $data.values.properties.addressPrefixes | Where-Object name -eq "AzureCloud.westeurope"
        Write-Host $ips
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
function GetIpListForRegion {
    $data = (Get-Content $output | ConvertFrom-Json)
    $data.values | Where-Object { $_.Name -EQ 'AzureCloud.westeurope' } | ForEach-Object { $_.properties.addressPrefixes }
}
```

or even shorter:

```
function GetIpListForRegion {
    (Get-Content $output | ConvertFrom-Json).values.Where{ $_.Name -EQ 'AzureCloud.westeurope' }.ForEach{ $_.properties.addressPrefixes }
}
```

To get prefixes for all regions into a single array:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Temp\ServiceTags_Public_20220214.json' | ConvertFrom-Json).values.ForEach{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name     = $_.Name
        Prefixes = ($_.properties.addressPrefixes -join ' ,')
    }
}
```